# Calling Swift method from Objective-C with block params

Tags: objective-c, swift

In Swift I have this type:

```
typealias AsyncBlock = (completionHandler: dispatch_block_t) -> Void
```

And I add this extension to NSOperationQueue:

```
extension NSOperationQueue {
    func addAsyncOperationWithBlock(block: AsyncBlock) {
        addOperation(MyOperation(block: block))
    }
}
```

I'd like to call it from Objective-C with:

```
[self.queue addAsyncOperationWithBlock:^{
   // code
}];
```

But what I get is this error on the code directly above:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(void)' to
parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(void (^ _Nonnull __strong)(void))'
```

Can anyone help stop the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The block's type you pass to the function(which takes 0 argument) is different from the declaration( which take 1 argument of type dispatch_block_t).

So you should use it like this:

```
  [self.queue addAsyncOperationWithBlock:^(dispatch_block_t completionHandler) {
      //do something...
  }];
```